# Images rendering differently within Windows and OS X browsers

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

I'm finding that particular images in my html documents are rendering with a purple border around them with any Windows browsers, but rendering perfectly within OS X browsers.

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="logo"><a href='/'><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer-container{
  width:900px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.header-container{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:900px;
  height:110px;
}
.logo{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  padding-top:12px;
}
```

Any ideas why Windows might be rendering it with a border while OS X does it perfectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a live link or a screenshot? The latter would be optimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img {
    border: 0
}
```

in your CSS will fix it.

What you're seeing is the default border in Internet Explorer for images inside links that have an `href` attribute that has been previously [`visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3avisited).

The reason this happens in the first place is that Internet Explorer presumably has something like this in its User Agent Stylesheet:

```
a:visited img {
    border: 2px solid purple
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers draw a blue or purple border around images when they're contained inside a link. The color is the same as for text links; blue for unvisited, purple for visited.

You can remove the border by using the following CSS:

```
a img {
    border: none;
}
```